# Minimal of sets of coins

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x < y < z,$ consider a set of coins (which have values of $x, y,$ and $z$ cents) with at least 1 coin of each value. If a set of coins exists such that it contains subsets of coins worth every whole number of cents up to 1000 cents, define its *minimal* to be the minimum number of coins in said set. Find the three least possible values of $z$ such that the minimal is equal to $97$ for some $x$ and $y.$

---

For this problem, I first attempted to use the [Chicken McNugget Theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbpa3NlIX2AhUllGoFHSRYDdoQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fartofproblemsolving.com%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%2FChicken_McNugget_Theorem&usg=AOvVaw3h6pvNRPLTh_LEXjYTktXk) but I was unable to come to any conclusion. What would be a good way to begin this problem?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are "stamps" = "coins"?  Are $(a,b)=(x,y)$?  Trusting that the answer to both is Yes, then it is worth noting that $1$ has to be in your triple (else you can't get $1$), so with $z$ being specified, all you need to do is to specify $y$.

Comment: I apologize, I have edited out the errors in the question.
After setting 1 coin equivalent to 1 cent, should I try and get $y$ very close to $z$?

Comment: I wouldn't think that $y$ should be close to $z$...after all, you can get every number close to $y$ by using a $y$ and a bunch of $1's$.  My instincts would be to space them equally.  Try $\{1,45,90\}$....see how that works.  Or maybe $(1,31,61)$ since $\sqrt {1000}\sim 31$.    The point is to try things to get a sense of how it works.

Comment: But since there is a condition that we can't use more than 97 coins total, wouldn't it be inoptimal to have a lot of 1's?

Comment: Feel free to try whatever you think works.  Seems clear to me that you need a bunch of small values, but the point is to try things.

Answer (score 0):

**A BIG HINT**

This is how to find the least possible value of $z$.

$97\times 10<1000$ and so we require $z\ge 11$.We shall now prove that there is a solution with $z=11$. Consider the values $x=1,y=7,z=11$ and let there be $a,b,c$ of each of these coins, respectively.

To obtain the values $1,2,3,4,5,6$ we require $a\ge6$. To obtain the value $8$ we require $b\ge1$.To obtain the value $1000$ we then require $c\ge 90$. We thus require $97$ coins as is required by the question. It is necessary to check that all values up to $1000$ can be obtained from these coins but that is straightforward.

Over to you to obtain the next two smallest values of $z$.